# printing in dockered flask-mqtt app only sometimes reaches docker logs

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a flask-mqtt app. This app recives a webhook and then sends a message to a mosquitto broker. The flask app, the software triggering the webhook (directus) and the mosquitto server are running each in a container on a docker compose network.

The messages get send successfully.

Some print statements in the code are not showing up in the docker logs.

I got it to print to the docker logs using the logger object of the flask instance, but I am still wondering why the original print statements did not work.

```
import logging
import sys

from flask import Flask
from flask_mqtt import Mqtt

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MQTT_BROKER_URL'] = 'mosquitto'
app.config['MQTT_BROKER_PORT'] = 1883  # default port for non-tls connection
app.config['MQTT_KEEPALIVE'] = 10  # set the time interval for sending a ping to the broker to 10 seconds
app.config['MQTT_TLS_ENABLED'] = False

app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
mqtt = Mqtt(app, mqtt_logging=True)

print("print")  # works
@mqtt.on_message()
def handle_mqtt_message(client, userdata, message):
    data = dict(
        topic=message.topic,
        payload=message.payload.decode("utf-8")
    )
    app.logger.info(data)  # works
    print(data)  # doesn't work


@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    message = "A new entry was created!"
    app.logger.info(message)  # works
    print(message) # doesn't work
    mqtt.publish('DIRECTUS', bytes(message, 'utf-8'))
    return "", 200


@mqtt.on_connect()
def handle_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    mqtt.subscribe('DIRECTUS')


@mqtt.on_log()
def handle_logging(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print('LOG: {}'.format(buf))  # works? For some reason?


app.run(host="app", port=8080, use_reloader=False, debug=True)
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  directus:
    image: directus/directus:9.22.1
    ports:
      - "8055:8055"
    volumes:
      - ./directus/database:/directus/database
      - ./directus/extensions:/directus/extensions
      - ./directus/uploads:/directus/uploads
    environment:
      KEY: "x"
      SECRET: "y"
      DB_CLIENT: "sqlite3"
      DB_FILENAME: "/directus/database/data.db"
      ADMIN_EMAIL: ""
      ADMIN_PASSWORD: ""
      CORS_ENABLED: true
  app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    volumes:
      - ./app/config/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
```